# What's the difference between T and T? in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What's the difference between:

```
fun <T, R> List<T>.map1(transform: (T) -> R): List<R> {
    return this.map(transform)
}
```

and

```
fun <T, R> List<T>.map2(transform: (T?) -> R): List<R> {
    return this.map(transform)
}
```

and

```
fun <T, R> List<T?>.map3(transform: (T?) -> R): List<R> {
    return this.map(transform)
}
```

In my test, `null` is accepted for ***all 3 transform functions above***, so: Is there any difference between `T` and `T?`?

Comment: *Declaring* a type parameter with a `?` isn't valid and doesn't compile. For example, the `<T?>` in  `fun <T?> myFunction(item: T)` isn't allowed. Could you look again at your second two examples? I don't think they are valid function declarations.

Comment: @Sam  yes something wrong, now its OK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your examples, `T` and `T?` are equivalent, but there are other cases where the `?` does make a difference.

When you declare a type parameter `<T>`, it doesn't have any restrictions on it. It's the same as writing `<T: Any?>`, and it means `T` will allow any sub-type of `Any?`. Adding a `?` to it would make it nullable, but `Any?` is already nullable, so the `?` doesn't change anything. That means that the set of types allowed by an ***unbounded*** type `T` is the same as the set of types allowed by `T?`.

As soon as you put restrictions on what `T` can be, things change, though. For example, in the following function, we declare a type parameter `<T: Any>`, restricting it so it's no longer nullable.

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> myFunction(item: T) // item can't be null
```

That means I can't pass `null` to `myFunction`. I can only call the function with a `null` argument if I change the type of the parameter to be `T?`.

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> myFunction(item: T?) // item can be null
```

---

Note that the `?` just annotates an existing type parameter. *Declaring* a type parameter with a `?` doesn't mean anything and doesn't compile. For example, `fun <T?> myFunction(item: T)` isn't valid Kotlin code.

Comment: is `T?` a sub-type of `T`, or a same-one-type of `T` but modified by `?` ?

Comment: Neither; `T?` is a supertype of `T`, since it can hold any value of type `T`, and it can also hold null.

Comment: An interesting side-note: a supertype doesn't technically have to allow more types than the base type, it just has to allow at least as many. When `T` is unbounded, `T?` is still treated as a supertype of `T`, even though it allows exactly the same set of types. The Kotlin compiler still applies normal supertype rules, so if I have a value of type `T?`, I'm not allowed to assign it to a variable of type `T`.

Comment: Mmmm.  (I had half a mind to mention the difference between ‘supertype’ (which can include the type itself) and ‘strict supertype’ (which can't), but I figured anyone who knew the difference wouldn't need to be told :-)

Comment: Small nitpick: the examples are not exactly equivalent, the second and third force `transform` to accept `null` regardless of `T`, while the first one can work if `transform` doesn't accept `null` and it happens to be that `T: Any`.